# NodeJS - Why is node reporting wrong version..?

Tags: node.js

I'm running Windows 7 Pro, and did have Node `v4.2.2`.

I've just been to https://nodejs.org/en/ and downloaded "node-v6.10.1-x64.msi" to upgrade to `v6.10.1` (the current LTS).

I installed this and restarted my machine, but now running `node -v` on the command line returns `v0.10.40`.

I've checked my system PATH variable, which has `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`. When I view the properties of `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` it shows "Product version" as `6.10.1` on the Details tab.

Why is `node -v` reporting `v0.10.40` when I've updated to `v6.10.1`..??

Comment: what does this command: `node -g -v` show?

Comment: @kaxi1993 I found the fix a few minutes after posting this. I've added the answer and I'll accept it when stack lets me in 2 days time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have Atom installed, which has it's own version of node installed at:

`C:\Program Files\Atom\resources\app\apm\bin`

The `node.exe` in here is `v0.10.40`.

This path was before `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` in the system PATH variables list, so doing `node -v` found the Atom version before the version in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`.

Manually putting `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` first in the system PATH variables list, and restarting the command prompt fixed this.

`node -v` now reports `v6.10.1`.