# Node showing different version than installed

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10

I've installed Node using the 20.11.0 LTS installer from https://nodejs.org/en/#home-downloadhead. Everything works as expected on my dev server, but my prod server is showing a different version (v21.6.1) than installed (both servers are Windows 10 (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter)).
Apps & features also shows the correct version (20.11.0).

[image]

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Node upwards of 10 times now, checked my PATH variables and checked whether I have anything else installed that could interact (as in [NodeJS - Why is node reporting wrong version..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42979222)), but no luck.
I'm assuming there's something in a cache somewhere, but I have no idea where that might be. I also tried running `npm cache clean`, but npm does not seem happy with that and immediately reported error, so I want to avoid using `--force`.

I don't use nvm as I have no use for multiple versions of node on these servers.

Comment: Use [`where node.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/51685) to figure out which Node you're running there. Then figure out why that is.

Comment: @AKX Already done. Running where node just shows me the one version of Node installed, namely 20.11.0

Comment: Okay, well, run `node` (so you get to the REPL) and look at Task Manager to double-triple-quadruple-check which EXE you end up running, and maybe look at its Properties to see which version its manifest has?